# Derivative and difference (intervals) between values

Tags: derivatives

Having only a high-school math background (~30 years ago), I'm having issues with the idea of derivative.

I understand that it's to be considered as a sort of "acceleration" of the values of a function, i.e. the rate at which such values change. Intuitively, this explains why a straight line has a derivative of `0`.

Does this mean that it's possible to calculate one value from the previous one by using the increment specified in the derivative?

For example, let's say we have a simple function, maybe

$ f(x)=x^2 $

The values of `f(x)` for `x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` are `1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...`. The increments between each value are `3, 5, 7, 9, ...`, but the derivative is `2x`, which means that the increments should be `2, 4, 6, 8, ...` ?

I know that I'm missing something, I just can't see what.

Comment: Functions have derivatives. A straight line is not a function, so it doesn't have a derivative. A straight line is the *graph* of a function, and that function has a derivative, but that derivative isn't zero unless the straight line is horizontal.

Comment: Let's write $\delta$ for an increment. Then $f(x+\delta)$ is *approximately* $f(x)+\delta f'(x)$, and the approximation gets better as the increment gets smaller. In your example the increment is one, which isn't very small, so the approximation isn't very good. Try it for $x=1$ and $x=1.01$, you should see the approximation using the derivative is very good.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is the rate at which the function increases/decreases as two points approach each other, the distance between them approaching zero. By the way, this has nothing to do with acceleration (which is actually given by the *second* derivative).

This is essentially what the limit definition of the derivative tells you:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

which is essentially $\frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}$ when the points are very, very close together.

Bonus question: given your function $f(x) = x^2$, can you use the limit definition of the derivative to prove that $f'(x) = 2x$?